# How to merge PDFs with only PHP and keep internal and external links

Tags: php, python, pdf, pdf-generation

How to merge PDFs with only PHP and keep internal and external links?

Simple question but I can't find a solution. It is no access to shell so pdftk and so on is unacceptable.

I'm looking for pure PHP (GPL-like licencing policy) design and can't find it for a week. It is IIS and Apache (Linux) server sides so my be Python will help too, but PHP is preferred.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried searching for PDF on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pdf&submit=search) and whatever the PHP equivalent is (they do have one, right?)? Because I see a whole lot of libraries that seem like they may work, and it wouldn't take that long to try a few of them and see.

Comment: Also, can you install binary extensions, or does the code need to be pure PHP or Python? (Or, if you can't install binary extensions, can you run Java? If so, you could use a Java library and write your script in Jython.)

Comment: I can't install binaries, it is Python already instaled so I can try to use it but pure PHP is better.

Comment: No I can't run java on server. And thanx for PyPI link, if it is no PHP design I'll try to make it with Python

Comment: It looks like PECL is the PHP equivalent, and [here](http://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name=PDF&bool=AND&submit=Search)'s a search for PDF. Most of them sound like wrappers around C libraries, which you won't be able to install… but look through them each and see, same as for the PyPI results.

Comment: One last thing: Do you actually need a GPL-like license, or just something GPL-compatible? Because the vast majority of Python modules have licenses like BSD, MIT, PSF, or Apache. You can use most of them as "part of a derived work" licensed under GPL, but they're not GPL-like themselves.

Comment: You right, all about GPL like I wanted to tell is that it is open source and free preferred. BSD, MIT and Apache are fine!

Comment: If you do the research yourself testing all those PHP and Python modules and find one that works for you, you should write and accept your own answer (unless you end up using PyPDF2, in which case you can just accept skendrick's answer), so when people come here with the same question in the future they'll find a useful answer.

Comment: I found a script that is implements links support to FPDI, wich is used in mPDF wich is best solution on PHP I found for now. Here it is: [link](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2020422#file-fpdi_with_annots-php) Now I'm researching how to make it work together with mPDF, so any kind of help needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Python module, PyPDF2 looks like it would work for you. http://knowah.github.io/PyPDF2/